# How to achieve a row index column in Emacs Org Mode using a Calc column rule

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to have a column in an org mode table that is a simple monotonically increasing value, i.e. the row number such that wnen I insert and remove random rows the index value adjusts automagically.  I suspect that this should be simple but it would appear I am making it way too difficult.  Mind you, I am a novice at using Emacs and org mode to build spreadsheets.  So a simple example spreadsheet where there are two columns, one the row index value and the other some fixed value, would be a perfect answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This example uses `@#` to get the row number. Similarly, `$#` returns the column number.

```
| row | data |
|-----+------|
| 2   | 0303 |
| 3   | 5123 |
| 4   | 41   |
| 5   | 4234 |
#+TBLFM: $1=@#
```

Comment: I tried it but got #ERROR instead of the numbers. Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: to execute the formula use C-c C-c on the "#+TBLFM: $1=@#" line

Answer (score 10):

It's often necessary, for example with descriptive rows, to start counting rows only from certain horizontal lines with 1, below for the first horizontal line: 
`#+TBLFM: $1=vlen(@I..0)`. This means calculate the length of the row range from the first hline `@I` (the second would be `@II`, ...) to the current (`0`) row.

```
|bla|blabla|
|---+------|
|1  | bla  |
|2  | bla  |
#+TBLFM: $1=vlen(@I..0)
```

or, for above example, also simply `#+TBLFM: $1=@#-1` :-)