# Numbering the rows in reverse order in an Emacs Org Mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'd like to do something like this:

[How to achieve a row index column in Emacs Org Mode using a Calc column rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267050/how-to-achieve-a-row-index-column-in-emacs-org-mode-using-a-calc-column-rule)

but I'd like the rows to be numbered in reverse order. I suspect this should be very easy, and should have something to do with @>, but e.g. $1=@>-@# doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example

```
| row | data |
|-----+------|
|   8 |      |
|   7 |      |
|-----+------|
|   6 |      |
|   5 |      |
|   4 |      |
|   3 | 5123 |
|   2 |      |
|   1 | 4234 |
#+TBLFM: $1='(- (length org-table-dlines) @#)
```

Comment: thanks - doesn't seem to work in my tables though (which don't have empty entries, but do have several columns, containing links etc - don't understand the syntax enough to know if that should make a difference, though).

Comment: Brilliant - that does it! Thank you very much.